# Program for abundant numbers <=k

Tags: c, algorithm

A natural number n > 0 is said to be an abundant number if the sum of its proper divisors (excluding itself) is greater than itself. For example, the number 12 is an abundant number because the sum of its divisors is 1+2+3+4+6=16, which is greater than 12 itself. in contrast, 16 is not an abundant number because the sum of its divisors is 1+2+4+8=15, which is not greater than 16. I have to write a program which will, for any entered natural number k, print all abundant numbers smaller or same as k. I have written a following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int k, sum=0, i, n;
    printf ("Enter k: ");
    scanf ("%d", &k);
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++) {
        int n=1;
        if (n%i==0);
        sum+=i;
    }
    if (n<sum);
    printf ("%d", &n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is not as expected. For example, if I enter 16 (or any other natural number), output is 6356716, which is definitely not correct. I just started learning programming and we just started with functions, so I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int abundant (int n)
{
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (n%i==0) sum+=i;
    if (n<sum) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    int i, k;
    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &k);
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++) {
        if (abundant(i))
            printf ("%d",&i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but output is exactly the same. Can somebody please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: *This program has no bugs in it, but output is not as expected* - don't you think this statement is problematic?

Comment: Anyway, replace `printf ("%d",&i);` with `printf ("%d",i);` and it will probably work.

Comment: In the first example, you have to remove the semicolons after the `if` conditionals

Comment: yeah `&i` is the address of `I`, that will just be something on the stack

Comment: Out of interest, which editor are you using? I don't understand how it's possible for source code to lack indenting in 2019. Also, enabling warnings would help, like probably tell you that `int n=1;` inside the for loop shadows the outer variable.

Comment: @Groo It has nothing to do with the editor, and everything to do with how code formatting is done here on SO.

Comment: You have semicolons after your `if` statements in the first code block

Comment: @Groo I use Code::Blocks.

Comment: @user3386109: I strongly believe that things like `if (n%i==0);` shouldn't be possible in 2019. Because of the warning, and because of the lack of indenting in the following line.

Comment: @user3386109 How is that? If you copy/paste indented text into the question it remains indented. Both spaces and tabs are copied as they are. Well, on Windows/Chrome at least.

Comment: @Mia09: I'd start by enabling all possible warnings and paying attention to them. [Compiling this in gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/Bq3ARH) already shows three bugs which have really simple fixes - your `if` statements have empty bodies, and `printf` prints the address of `i`. Also, when you declare `int n=1;` inside a block, it's no longer the same `n` as in the outer block. Also, your `for` loop inside the `abundant` function should have braces and indenting to specify which part you are trying to repeat.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you copy/paste text into the question, it isn't displayed as code. The process by which text is converted into a code block seems to elude most newcomers to SO.

Comment: @Groo Perhaps I misunderstood your comment. I was under the impression that you thought the code in the question represented what the OP was seeing in their editor.

Comment: @user3386109 That might result in some badly formatted code, but not in flat one as in this question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253431/encryption-in-c-using-a-caesar-cipher#comment104716967_59253431)

Comment: @EugeneSh. My code doesn't have any bugs; it works on my computer. It crashes with a segmentation fault on my friend's computer, but that doesn't mean it has bugs.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf ("%d", &k);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current code, any value returned, other than 1, indicates an error.

Comment: regarding: `int n=1;
        if (n%i==0);`  What are you expecting this to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int k, i, j;
    printf("Enter k: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                sum += j;
        }
        if (sum > i)
            printf("%d is abundant\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```